# In Google Cloud SQL, do the backups have inadequate privacy?

Tags: google-cloud-sql, privacy

According to [a page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/backups)
in the docs for Google Cloud SQL:

> Backup data is stored in two regions for redundancy

Suppose that the region for the database instance has been chosen so that the laws and
state organizations respect privacy.  Doesn't the above line
mean that the data could be copied to another region where
the laws and state organizations are much less respectful of
privacy?

If the answer is "no", I would appreciate a pointer to some official
Google source that states this.

Answer (score 0):

List of regions and zones for Compute services is available here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/backups#where_backups_are_stored states:

> If there are two regions on a continent, the backup data remains on the same continent.